# Compare 2 csv files and replace updated values

Tags: csv

I have 2 csv files and I'm looking for a way to compare them using a specific column, and once a match is found I need to take the value of another column from the matched row and put it in the corresponding column of the other record.

I'll try to explain a little bit more.

One csv has `product_id,product_name,brand_name,price`
the other has `product_id,product_category,product_name,brand_name,price`

I need to compare the 2 files by finding the rows that have a matching `product_id` value, and once found I need to take the `price` value from file 1 and put it to the matched record's `price` in file 2.

After extensive research I've come to the conclusion that this maybe achievable with powershell.

Does anyone have any ideas about how I could do that? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you need to automate this or is just one time action?

Comment: just once. I'm gonna do it again in the future but manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since is just a one time action. you could open the csv files in a spreadsheet (google docs, excel, ...) and do a VLOOKUP. Is easy:

To demonstrate this imagine the following spreadsheet where both csv files are side by side. First from column A to B and the second on column D to F

```
  |    A       |   B   | C |      D     |         E        |   F  
--+------------+-------+---+------------+------------------+-------
1 | product_id | price |   | product_id | product_category | price
2 |          1 |  29.9 |   |          2 |       SOME CAT 1 | =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D2;A:B;2;FALSE); "NULL")
3 |          2 |  35.5 |   |          3 |       SOME CAT 2 | =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D3;A:B;2;FALSE); "NULL")
```

The `VLOOKUP` function will search for an **exact match** of the value of D2 cell on the first column of the region A:B, and return the value from the second column of that region. The `iferror`will return NULL if the `VLOOKUP` fails.

So in this case on cell F2, will look for the product id "2" (Cell d2) on the column A. It founds the product id "2" in row 3, and return the price "35.5" (being the second row of the range A:B). After all rows have been calculated the result will be:

```
  |    A       |   B   | C |      D     |         E        |   F  
--+------------+-------+---+------------+------------------+-------
1 | product_id | price |   | product_id | product_category | price
2 |          1 |  29.9 |   |          2 |       SOME CAT 1 | 35.5
3 |          2 |  35.5 |   |          3 |       SOME CAT 2 | NULL
```

Comment: very interesting, going to try it right now and I'll be back to report. Thank you for such a descriptive answer, it must have taken you some time to write it. I really appreciate it

Comment: Hello again. That worked like a charm, I can't thank you enough

Answer (score 1):

One could also use `awk` for this; say you have:

```
$ cat a.csv 
#product_id,product_name,brand_name,price
1,pname1,bname1,100
10,pname10,bname10,200
20,pname20,bname20,300

$ cat b.csv 
#product_id,product_category,product_name,brand_name,price
3,pcat3,pname3,bname3,42
10,pcat10,pname10,bname10,199
20,pcat20,pname20,bname20,299
30,pcat10,pname30,bname30,420
```

With the "FNR==NR" approach (see e.g. [> The Unix shell: comparing two files with awk](http://theunixshell.blogspot.dk/2012/12/i-have-two-files-file-1-contains-3.html)):

```
$ awk -F, 'FNR==NR{if(!/^#/){a[$1]=$0;next}}($1 in a){split(a[$1],tmp,",");printf "%d,%s,%s,%s,%d\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,tmp[4];}' a.csv b.csv 
10,pcat10,pname10,bname10,200
20,pcat20,pname20,bname20,300
```

With reading each file into an array (see e.g. [Awking it – how to load a file into an array in awk | Tapping away](http://magvar.wordpress.com/2011/05/18/awking-it-how-to-load-a-file-into-an-array-in-awk/)):

```
$ awk -F, 'BEGIN{while(getline < "a.csv"){if(!/^#/){a[$1]=$0;}}close("a.csv");while(getline < "b.csv"){if($1 in a){split(a[$1],tmp,",");printf "%d,%s,%s,%s,%d\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,tmp[4];}}close("b.csv");}' 
10,pcat10,pname10,bname10,200
20,pcat20,pname20,bname20,300
```

In essence, the two approaches do the same thing:

- read the first file (`a.csv`), and store its lines in an associative array `a`, keyed/indexed by the first field `$1` of that line (in this case, `product_id`);
- then read the second file (`b.csv`); and if the first field of each of its lines is found in the array `a`; then output the first four fields of the current line of `b.csv`; and the fourth field (`price`) from the corresponding entry in array `a`

The difference is, that with the `FNR==NR` approach, specify the input files on the command line as arguments to `awk`, and basically you can only identify the first file as "special" so you can store it as an array; with the second approach, each input file could be parsed in a separate array - however, the input files are specified in the `awk` script itself, not in the arguments to `awk` - and since then you don't even need to use arguments to `awk`, the entirety of the `awk` script needs to happen within a `BEGIN{...}` block.

When lines are being read from the files, they are automatically split in fields according to `-F,` command line options, which sets comma as delimiter; however, when retrieving lines stored in the array, we have to `split()` them separately

Breakdown for the first:

```
FNR==NR    # if FNR (input record number in the current input file) equals NR (total num records so far)
           # only true when the first file is being read 
{
  if(!/^#/)  # if the current line does not `!` match regex `/.../` of start `^` with `#`
  {
     a[$1]=$0; # assign current line `$0` to array `a`, with index/key being first field in current line `$1`
     next      # skip the rest, and start processing next line
  }
}
               # --this section below executes when FNR does not equal NR;--  
($1 in a)                                      # first, check if first field `$1` of current line is in array `a`
{
  split(a[$1],tmp,",");                          # split entry `a[$1]` at commas into array `tmp`
  printf "%d,%s,%s,%s,%d\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,tmp[4];  # print reconstructed current line, 
                                                 # taking the fourth field from the `tmp` array
}
```

Breakdown for the second:

```
BEGIN{ # since no file arguments here, everything goes in BEGIN block
  while(getline < "a.csv"){  # while reading lines from first file 
    if(!/^#/){               # if the current line does not `!` match regex `/.../` of start `^` with `#`
      a[$1]=$0;              # store current line `$0` to array `a`, with index/key being first field in current line `$1`
    }
  }
  close("a.csv");
  while(getline < "b.csv"){  # while reading lines from second file 
    if($1 in a){                                 # first, check if first field `$1` of current line is in array `a`
      split(a[$1],tmp,",");                         # (same as above)
      printf "%d,%s,%s,%s,%d\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,tmp[4]; # (same as above)
    } 
  }
  close("b.csv");
} # end BEGIN
```

---

Note about the execution with `FNR==NR`:

```
$ awk -F, 'FNR==NR{print "-";} (1){print;}' a.csv b.csv # or:
$ awk -F, 'FNR==NR{print "-";} {print;}' a.csv b.csv 
-
#product_id,product_name,brand_name,price
-
1,pname1,bname1,100
-
10,pname10,bname10,200
-
20,pname20,bname20,300
#product_id,product_category,product_name,brand_name,price
3,pcat3,pname3,bname3,42
10,pcat10,pname10,bname10,199
20,pcat20,pname20,bname20,299
30,pcat10,pname30,bname30,420

$ awk -F, 'FNR==NR{print "-";} FNR!=NR{print;}' a.csv b.csv 
-
-
-
-
#product_id,product_category,product_name,brand_name,price
3,pcat3,pname3,bname3,42
10,pcat10,pname10,bname10,199
20,pcat20,pname20,bname20,299
30,pcat10,pname30,bname30,420
```

That means that the "*this section below executes when FNR does not equal NR;*" comment above is in principle wrong - even if that is how that particular example ends up behaving.